# Django: Why does database login every query?

Tags: django, pyodbc

In my settings.py, I have a database configured.  I have a page that issues a sql query against the database defined in settings.py every 10 seconds.

I have been using it for 1 year now and never had any issues with it.

My database admin ran a login audit on our database.  As it turns out, each individual single sql query has a unique login to the database.  His audit took 5 minutes to run *just today* and it is because of my django application logging in.

I was pretty surprised to find out that every query that is issues has a unique login attempt to the database.

Is there anyway to create a "session" for the backend database in settings.py.  I really feel that the application should have a single login and use that session to issue commands.

Did I miss a setting to do this?

[image]

Sql login audit:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting `CONN_MAX_AGE` in `DATABASES` setting.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#persistent-connections)

> Persistent connections avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection to the database in each request. They’re controlled by the CONN_MAX_AGE parameter which defines the maximum lifetime of a connection. It can be set independently for each database.
> The default value is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing the database connection at the end of each request. To enable persistent connections, set CONN_MAX_AGE to a positive integer of seconds. For unlimited persistent connections, set it to None.